# module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Treeview'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to use Treeview in a project but just got hit with an error; `module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Treeview'`

Here's my code;

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk

class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.EmpInfo = ttk.Treeview(self.master).grid(row = 1 , column = 1)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    a = MainGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Do i need to pip install more stuff or am i just using Treeview wrong?

Comment: `from tkinter import ttk`, and then `self.EmpInfo = ttk.Treeview(self.master)`

Comment: @HenryYik Thanks for the reply, i tired that and it did not work.

Comment: `import tkinter as ttk` isn't doing what you think. It's not importing ttk, it's just importing tkinter and giving it a different name. That won't cause it to have the `Treeview` class.

Answer (score 7):

You are using `Treeview` wrong. It's in the ttk module. You need to import ttk, and then use `Treeview` from the ttk module

```
from tkinter import ttk
...
self.EmpInfo = ttk.Treeview(...)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried `import tkinter as ttk` which still gave me the same error.

Comment: @hiihihihelloo: you may have other problems, but I can say with absolute certainty that this is part of the problem. It is simply a fact that `tk` does not have a `Treeview` widget.

Comment: I tried to uninstall and reinstall python but got the same result, could it possibly be a tkinter problem? Is there anyway i can update tkinter?

Comment: @hiihihihelloo: no, the problem is exactly what my answer says and what the error message is telling you. Tkinter _does not have_ a treeview widget. You must import ttk, and use `ttk.Treeview`.

Comment: bro, i did and i got the exact same error. I'll go ahead and update my current posts code to show you.

Comment: @hiihihihelloo: look more closely at my answer. You're not importing ttk, you're simply importing tkinter and giving it a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk
```

You first import tkinter as `tk`, then import the entire library, then import the library *again* but this time as `ttk`.
So either import the library as a whole with `*`. Or choose an alias such as `tk`.

Additionnaly, I think you should try `from tkinter import ttk` and then call `ttk.Treeview`.

Be careful next time ;)